# На странице "тур" не переведена часть текста

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, тур

На странице [тур](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) часть текста не переведена под заголовком "Улучшайте сообщения с помощью правок или комментариев".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[Transifex:3704-3706](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/63221585?key=20e74251fe9e5120449cf94f87fde21a):

> You can always comment on **your own** questions and answers. Once you earn $rep$ reputation, you can comment on anybody's post.

Есть похожая строка [Tx:969](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40262632?key=40e033bc260ca50955a622d4c43277af):

> This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post.
>
> Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора уточнить вопрос, оставьте комментарий к вопросу. Вы можете оставлять любое количество комментариев под своим сообщением. Когда ваша репутация достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете комментировать сообщения любого пользователя.

Comment: Напомню о предложении полностью переработать содержимое страницы Тур. [Более релевантный пример для страницы «Тур»](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1152)

Comment: Поскольку других вариантов нет, оставляю этот.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для всех трех вариантов, максимально близко к уже имеющемуся переводу.

> <s>Вы можете оставлять любое количество комментариев под своими вопросами и ответами. Когда ваша репутация достигнет $rep$, вы сможете комментировать сообщения любого пользователя.</s>
>
> Вы всегда можете оставлять комментарии под **своими** вопросами и ответами. Когда ваша репутация достигнет $rep$, вы сможете комментировать сообщения других пользователей

Вместе с этими тремя подправил ещё одну строку:

> Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора уточнить вопрос, оставьте комментарий к вопросу. Вы всегда можете оставлять комментарии под **своими** вопросами и ответами. Когда ваша репутация достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете комментировать сообщения любого пользователя.
> Уже применил этот вариант. Если будет что-то лучше, можно заменить.

Comment: Повторяющееся "любой" совсем глаз режет. Почему бы не сделать "Вы можете оставлять комментарии под своими вопросами и ответами. Когда ваша репутация достигнет $rep$, вы сможете комментировать сообщения других пользователей" ?

Comment: @Suvitruf: нравится, принято.